# What is the most performant way to get data of one rails application by another rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two rails applications (both now on Rails 3.1.1), and they work nicely. However, I have a dependence between the two. Application `A` uses data of application `B` by linking to it. These links are created automatically, but they have to be computed by doing a lookup to the data of application `B`. I'm working on Windows 7 with Ruby 1.9.2 and Thin as web server, and this will not be changed :-(

I have tried the following:

- Use just a RESTful resource, so defined a controller, called its action (`get_xml_obj` with some params in it), read the needed values from the XML. Worked, but needs around 0.5s to 1s per call.
- Replaced it by [ActiveResource#find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-find) which worked as well, but with the same performance as the solution before.
- I have installed nginx and configured it so, that the connection are keepalive, so that the connection handling should be much faster. But noticed no difference at all when calling `B` from `A`.

When I compare the time spent, these are typical examples (here with 4 references in one web page):

Application A:

```
Started GET "/tasks/search_task/1803" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-02 14:11:04 +0100

  Processing by TasksController#search_task as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1803"}
Rendered tasks/_tooltip.html.haml (4529.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4532ms (Views: 4527.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
cache: [GET /tasks/search_task/1865] miss
```

Application B:

```
cache: [GET /service/get_xml_obj?key=notice&value=rails] miss

Started GET "/service/get_xml_obj?key=notice&value=rails" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-
11-02 14:11:05 +0100
  Processing by ServiceController#get_xml_obj as */*
  Parameters: {"key"=>"notice", "value"=>"rails"}
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

and 3 other calls with a similar length (< 10ms).

So is there something I can do to tune the retrieval (without accessing the database directly)? Do you know of any good documentation how to measure and tune the web server and middleware? These are only personal applications, so there is no way of deploying them on a decent server. I use a cache for the retrieved information, so it gets better over time, but 1 second is too much to wait for. And there may be more than 1 or 2 links in a page I want to render.

Comment: Can't you go directly to the database?

Comment: Perhaps I can (will be the next try to get better performance). But it has some drawbacks: 2 database connections, duplication of a lot of model objects. And of course, I would like to see that there is a performant Rails solution available.

Comment: Put the shared models into a plugin/gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally gave up and implemented the following:

- Added file `b.rb` to my `models` directory in application `A`.
- Included there all raw models, where the base  models (used sti) are defined like that:

  ```
  class Notice < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.establish_connection(
      :adapter => "sqlite3",
      :database  => "../b/db/dev.db"
    )
  end
  ...
  ```
- I am now able to ask: `Notice.where(:key => 'rails')` which results in a real Rails model object.

The whole thing was implemented in around 20 minutes, and now there is no difference in including no link from application `A` to `B` to include 5 links.

At some point in time, I would like to know what is the slow part in using RESTful resources here ...